# Popups Do Not Appear In React Native WebView (PayUMoney)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I've seen multiple questions regarding this on StackOverflow but unfortunately, none of them have been solved.

In my case, I'm using PayuMoney inside a WebView to execute a transaction. Payumoney by **default opens up a new window while processing a transaction which is not visible inside the react native's webview but is apparently visible in mobile browsers.**

According to this answer - [Enable Popups in React Native WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48118159/enable-popups-in-react-native-webview), I added

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true); // To enable these by default
```

And also this,

```
@ReactProp(name = "javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically")
  public void setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(WebView view, boolean isCan) {
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(isCan);
  }

  @ReactProp(name = "supportMultipleWindows")
  public void setSupportMultipleWindows(WebView view, boolean supports) {
    view.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(supports);
  } //To add these as valid props for the WebView Component
```

Additionally, I have also tried multiple npm packages which provide different implementations of WebView but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Were you able to solve this ?

Comment: No, I wasn't able to solve this. I had to use the redirect checkout feature in PayuMoney instead of the Bolt Checkout feature. However, if you have some other problem you're trying to solve, I'm not sure if there is a solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52556024/payumoney-integration-in-react-native checkout my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any payment solution for security purposes using popup browser cannot be used with react-native-webview . It most often is result of design of security with cookies and browser.

I can confirm this behavior for

1. payumoney - You can read more and follow -
   https://github.com/payu-intrepos/custom_browser_react_native/issues/1
2. getsimpl - You can read more and follow
   https://github.com/GetSimpl/react-native-simpl-zero-click-sdk/issues/3

Response from dev team.

> Unlike Razorpay, we identify a device/browser of the user using
>   cookies so that we can skip the OTP flow for subsequent orders by
>   users using the same identified device. This means that the moment we
>   load the OTP UI in a popup, a cookie is stored against the same popup
>   window i.e. against getsimpl.com domain. Since the popup is a
>   standalone window loading the UI from getsimpl.com domain, browsers
>   allow to save cookies against the same domain.
>
> However, if we switch to razorpay like modal, there wont be a popup
>   window. This means the main window domain would be whatever merchant
>   domain Simpl has been integrated on, say bigbazaar.com and when the
>   OTP UI loads in an iframe (inside a modal) its domain would be
>   getsimpl.com domain. None of the browsers allow, for security reasons,
>   to store a cookie from bigbazaar.com to getsimpl.com. This phenomena
>   is called a third-party-cookie problem.
>
> This is the main reason we will never ever switch to Modal version
>   like razorpay.

***Also, only razorpay uses iframe and hence can be used with react-native-webview***

Comment: Yeah, you are right I suppose. I used the redirect checkout version by payumoney which made my life easier. If someone is stuck with this problem, I'd recommend using redirect checkout instead of the latest bolt checkout

Comment: Can i reach out to you on chat?

Comment: Sure, you can :)